# Why doesn't memcache work?

Tags: unix, python, django, memcached

```
from django.core.cache import cache
    def testcache():
        cache.set('test','I am putting this message in',3333)
        print cache.get('test')
```

It just prints "**None**"

This is in "ps aux":

```
dovr      2241  0.0  0.8  57824  2144 ?        Ssl  04:20   0:00 memcached -d -u root -m 3900 -p 11211
dovr      2247  0.0  3.7  83696  9800 pts/2    S+   04:20   0:00 python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And this is in my settings.py:

```
CACHE_BACKEND = 'memcached://MYIPADRESS:11211/'
```

By the way, it worked before, but not anymore! I don't know why. So weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some questions:

- Is your memcache server configured to listen on your public ip address or does it only listen on localhost?
- Is MYIPADDRESS local or public?

In case MYIPADDRESS is a public one and your server only listens on 127.0.0.1 this doesn't work. You'd need to make your server listen on 0.0.0.0 to listen on all interfaces.

More questions:

- How did you install memcached? Which OS / distro?
- What's the memcache library you're using? memcache? cmemcached? cmemcache? pylibmc? There are many out there...